# Javascript: window.open has inconsistent url results

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.open

I have the following Javascript code which I am running in Chrome on two different machines:

```
var url = userId + '?service=retrieve';
window.open(url, "_self");
```

The url before this code runs is http://localhost:12008/password-services.

After it runs, on one machine I get http://localhost:12008/password-services/123?service=retrieve (where user Id is 123). This is the desired effect.

But on the other machine, I get http://localhost:12008/123?service=retrieve. It removes password-services from the url. this is not what I want.

Exactly the same code is being run on both machines.

Why the discrepancy? What can I do to get consistent results on both machines?

Both machines are running the code in a VM hosted in Windows. Even the VMs are the same (Windows Server 2008 R2) - both came from the same source. Both running Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 m.

I can't see any difference between the two setups (originally I was signed into Chrome on only one machine, but I corrected that and it made no difference). What might be making the difference??

Comment: If the code you provide is true as is, the url doesn't contains the "http://localhost...".  It just has the userId + 'service=retrieve'.  Do you meant to instead of : var url =, it should be url = url + '/'+ userId + '?service=retrieve' ?

Comment: @leng, it's a relative url.

Comment: @ClareSudbery, try using [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object: `var u=new URL(location.href); u.search = 'service=retrieve'; window.open(u.href, "_self");`

Comment: @wOxxOm: Haha, yes, I have discovered that if I use window.location.href + "\" + userId + '?service=retrieve', it works on both machines.
Here is an interesting thing though: on the misbehaving machine, the result is this: http://localhost:12008/password-services/123?service=retrieve. On the other machine, I get this: http://localhost:12008/password-services//123?service=retrieve.
The only difference now is that the misbehaving machine has no trailing slash on window.location.href. Luckily it works either way. I still have no idea why they are different!